# MyObject[] return json object instead of array when size < 2

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-ws

In my REST webservice that produces json, I have a method that return an object that contains an array of MyObject. Now I have the problem that when the MyObject[] has only one item in it, it show a single object instead of an array. Example;

If the object has a single item;

```
{ "myObjectList": { "name": "Test", "value": "Wicked"} }
```

But if there are more than one items;

```
{ "myObjectList": [{ "name": "Test", "value": "Wicked"}, { "name": "Test2", "value": "Not so wicked"}] }
```

Because the JSON is parsed, and I don't want to check if a variable is an array on the client-side, I was wondering if there is there a way to make my webservice always put out an array as an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug, the solution can be found here;

http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/configuring_json_for_restful_web

Answer (score 0):

The link in the existing answer didn't work for me. But the following code is working:
put it inside JAXBContextResolver .java , Ask me if anything isn't clear.

```
    package model;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONJAXBContext;

@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver < JAXBContext > {

    private JAXBContext context;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtyp`enter code here`es")
    private Class[] types = {CarModel.class,CarProduction.class,Ride.class,GeneralResponse.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {

         //rides is the jsonarray ``that will be converted to array if has one 
        //one object, else it will return as jsonObject 
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("rides").build(),
                types);

    }




    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        System.out.println("Inside getContext"+objectType+");;;;;;");
        for (Class<?> type : types) {


            if (type == objectType) {
                System.out.println("converttttted");

                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's has been a while so I'll have to refresh my memory. The link-only answer would be flagged as insufficient in this day and age, so your answer is probably better. Just to be sure, what did not work; The actual link or the solution on the page in the link?